# Stuck auto-renewing the new managed SSL on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I've tried switching to the new [Managed SSL](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html) on my Google App Engine app, and it's been stuck at `auto-renewing` for over 24 hours. Anyone know an estimate of how long does this take?

[image: auto-renewing]

Comment: I'd *guess* that 24 hours is too much. I'd also guess contacting support is your primary option here.

Comment: Disable adblocker or uBlock or anything like that in the page. Reload and try again. (Answer instead of comment cause I can't comment, but I thought I'd share to see if this works for you)

Comment: Please visit [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/_ErrNAHN3_4/7NfcZS9WBQAJ) for my answer to similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that `CNAME` record of your domain is not correctly configured. Login to your domain registrar and add / modify the `CNAME` record of your domain to point to `ghs.googlehosted.com`.

After updating the `CNAME`, it would take some time for DNS record to be propagated and the managed security should take place.